# Can't get to Forgot Password page in Lightning Community

Tags: lightning-community, forgot-your-password

I am trying to get to the Forgot Password page in my Lightning Community because it currently has a typo on it.  When I am in Builder & try to go to the page, it just hangs and never brings up the page.  I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome.  I am not having this problem with other Community pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Salesforce & they emptied my Sites.com trash can to resolve the issue.  When I probed about how I can do this, I was told it can only be done by Salesforce.  Below is the response...

You have a new comment on Case #22179008

Salesforce Support  March 25 at 8:00 PM EDT
Hello Michele,

I apologize but the information regarding on how to empty a trashcan is internal information so I won't be able to share it with you.

As for the reason, I believe that you have added a custom component with the page then when you have removed it, some data was not removed so emptying a trashcan solved the issue.

Let me know if you still have any issues or concern regarding the case or if we can now proceed with closing this one.

In case of no response, my next case update will be tomorrow between 10am - 12pm Eastern time.

Answer (score 1):

The Community Builder will execute the `init` method of all custom components on a page when you try to view it in the builder.  If there is a failure in any of the `init` methods, you may not be able to view the page properly.

Also, if an init method does a redirect in certain situations, you may find that the builder forces the redirect and so you cannot view the original page.

The workaround is to temporarily comment out the `init` methods of the custom components on the page so that the builder can display the page.

Comment: David...how do I see what components are on the page if I can't get the page to come up in Builder?  I understand what you are saying about commenting out the init.  However, I don't know which components are coming into play at the momen.

Comment: Actually I see the components.  I can access that part of the page.  I will try commenting out inits.

Comment: Well, I still need help.  I can see that the Forgot Password Community page has 4 components on it.  Three are rich content components and one is a Forgot Password component.  When I create a new test Community page, I don't see an option to add the Forgot Password component to it.  When I look at the inaccessible Forgot Password Community page via Builder, I can see that there is an Identity Forgot Password component.  I am not sure how to see this component.  I don't see it in the Developer Console.

Comment: I Builder next to the Forgot Password component on the page, it just has a trash can.  It doesn't have the normal option that components have where you can click it and you will be taken to the component in the Developer's Console where you can see the code.

Comment: I just created a new blank page variation of the ForgotPassword page.  It has no components on it & it is hanging.  I can't get to the page to add components, etc.

Comment: If that's the case, you should open a case with Salesforce support.

Comment: I seem to be having this problem with all of my Login pages in production.  It is not happening in my sandbox.  Because I don't use the Register page, I removed all of the components from it.  The problem is still happening.  I will open a case with Salesforce.